# How can I store a single config IP address in a per-user situation for an Alexa Skill?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cloud, alexa-skills-kit

I'm making a python universal remote out of my Raspberry Pi, and I'm going to connect it to an Alexa skill. I've already built a server on my pi that is capable of doing all of the IR stuff, and I can hit it from my Lambda skill to properly activate my devices.

The issue is, I want to publish the Alexa skill so that I can actually use it. On the other hand, I don't really want to make my pi's IP address public for anyone who downloads my app, and I don't really want to implement a whole persistent data solution just to keep track of a single IP address.

Is there a way for me to store some sort of config in the Alexa cloud without implementing a database solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is your intention to never make the skill public?  If that is the case you can keep the skill in test mode indefinitely so that it is only accessible to you.

Also, how are you connecting to your Pi from a Lambda skill?  You could skip Lambda entirely and use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [Yaler](https://yaler.net/) that runs on your Pi and will gives you an https URL linked to a port on your Pi that you can enter into the Alexa skill builder.

I put this guide together a while ago but it should still work.  I have been running an Alexa skill directly from a Raspberry Pi to control various devices in my house for over a year using [flask-ask](https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask).

[Control Raspberry Pi GPIO With Amazon Echo and Python](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-With-Amazon-Echo-and-Pyt/)

If you want to get fancy, instead of ngrok or Yaler you could set up a free-tier-eligible linux ec2 instance in AWS, use [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) to forward the server port on your Pi to port 80 or 443 on the ec2 instance, and then setup a domain name in AWS and route it to the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your Pi as an AWS IoT device.[IoT SDK Setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdk-setup.html), There are easy to use protocols to manage the bi-directional communication. It will provide you a secure interface between lambda and your Pi, while also providing an easy to use, and consistent, data object.